# Asterisk AMI call history

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

is possible to get call history (log) from Asterisk over AMI ?

I need to read history (log) every 10 minutes, parse calls (duration, from, to...) and store this data in our CRM database.

In CRM i have stored SIP for hardware phone, so I can recognize who is who. But I am not sure if I can read history and where is history stored.

**I can't use ARI in this case**

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to go through call history is using Call Detail Record (CDR).
You can configure Asterisk to store those in specific directory.

It is a very simple CSV-like format.

You can even configure Asterisk to put CDR's directly into some SQL database.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. :)